# Spring MVC - @Scope("session") doesn't work like intended

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

i'm trying to develop simple flashcards app using Spring MVC.
Everything went fine until i tried to test it with multiple users.
I wanted every user to log in and assumed that @Session("scope") will create every bean anew for every user. It seems to me that this doesn't work - i logged in on 3 different devices and it is all connected, when i log in on one computer the same is logged on the second and third. When i log out - all computers are logged out.

I'm confused - please help:

```
   @Controller
@Scope("session")
@SessionAttributes({"logged", "LoggedUser"})


@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {


 public   static NewUser loggedUser;

    @Autowired
    private NewUserRepository newUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FlashcardRepository flashcardRepository;



(.....)
```

maybe it has something to do with this static variable - i want it to be separate for every browser session.

Comment: Do you know what `static` means for fields? There is no relation between your `@SessionAttributes` `LoggerUser` and the class field `loggedUser`.

Answer (score 0):

`@Scope` annotation is for making whole *bean* session aware with all it's properties. `@SessionAttributes` makes your *model* object session aware, which you need to populate and manage manually (init for example).

As @Sotirios Delimanolis wrote, you should learn the difference between static and non-static properties.

If I'm corrent, you're looking for something like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({IndexController.LOGGED_USER_MODEL })
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    private static final String LOGGED_USER_MODEL = "loggedUser";
    public NewUser loggedUser;

    @Autowired
    private NewUserRepository newUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FlashcardRepository flashcardRepository;

    @ModelAttribute(LOGGED_USER_MODEL)
    public NewUser initLoggedUser() {
        //this is to make sure that our session attribute model is always populated, otherwise Spring throws exception
        return new NewUser();
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public Model someMethod(@ModelAttribute(LOGGED_USER_MODEL) NewUser loggedUser) {
        //do something with logged user, populete with repository for example
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(...)

```
 if (loggedUser!=null){
        model.addAttribute("LoggedUser", loggedUser.getName());}

        if (loggedUser==null){
            model.addAttribute("LoggedUser", "not logged");}
        return "index";
    }
```

(...)

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/logUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logUser(@ModelAttribute NewUser newUser, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


        if (!newUserRepository.findByName(newUser.getName()).isEmpty()) {

          loggedUser=newUserRepository.findByName(newUser.getName()).get(0);
            DrillController.queueKeys=null;
DrillController.cards.clear();
DrillController.wrongAnswers=null;
           if (loggedUser.getNumberOfRepsSetting()!=null) {
               DrillController.NumberOfReps = Integer.parseInt(loggedUser.getNumberOfRepsSetting());
           }
        }



    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Maybe there is something wrong with this? i'm not sure if this static field is created anew with every session?

Sorry for all that confusion - I just want that this static field is null with every new browser session. I understand how static works in plain java, but i'm confused how it works in Spring context with beans and multiple users. Am i thinking correctly here?

Answer (score -1):

Ok - i know what is wrong... every time the new bean is created (with session scope) the static field remains the same. i should store login-data in non-static variable... sorry for confusion and thank you!